# How to get the IDs of the all the groups that a specific user is member of in Azure Ad using Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-active-directory

I want a way to get all the groups that a specific user has membership in them in Azure AD.
I have tried this, but this takes a lot of time, since it checks for the user membership status in every group in the tenant. I want a faster way to get the groups that a user is member of.

What I am using right now is:

```yaml
- name: Verify membership of the specific user for each group
  azure.azcollection.azure_rm_adgroup_info:
    object_id: "{{ item }}"
    check_membership: "USER_ID"
    tenant: "TENANT_ID"
  with_items: " {{ groups_ids_list }}"
  register: group_info
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after some digging around, I found something. It brings down the runtime significantly. It is this task:

```
   - name: Return all groups that a user is member of them
  azure.azcollection.azure_rm_adgroup_info:
    tenant: "TENANT_ID"
    check_membership: "USER_ID"
    all: true
```

With the original task, the runtime was around 10 minutes, but with this one it is reduced to around 2 minutes. I think there is still room for improvement, and there may be a way to achieve this in a more optimized and time efficient manner.